# Is it possible to add context menu items for popup icon with MV3 Chrome extensions?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In MV2 version, it's easy to add context menu items like this:

[image]

But in MV3, the old way doesn't work. Is there any way that I can achieve that?

Comment: It still works, but `browser_action` is renamed to `action`.